# Why's isn't my auth token showing up in the auth user object even though it returns an auth token?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I'm using Laravel Passport for user login.

What could be the reason why accessToken won't show up upon `dd(auth('web')->user());`?  All the information I need for the user appears in the object except for the auth token.

Upon `dd($loginToken);` - I see the token so we can rule out that a token doesn't exist.

Could it be because I'm using `auth('web')->user()` even though my project revolves around using `api.php` rather than `web.php`?  If I switch it to `auth('api')->user()`, I get a 500 error which's seems to be a weird behavior.

I appreciate any feedback and/or suggestion for improvement :)

Here's my login code:

```
public function login(Request $request) {

$credentials = ['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password];

if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials, false)) {
    $loginToken = auth('web')->user()->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
    dd(auth('web')->user());
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully logged in',
        'loginToken' => $loginToken
    ]);
}

    return $this->sendError('Unauthorized.', ['error' => 'Unauthorized']);
}
```

Here's my `auth.php`:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Hi, please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Goodluck 

Answer (score 1):

This may seem a bit old to answer, but just so others could benefit.

I'm sure you hadn't imported `HasApiTokens` trait from `Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens` in your `User` model.

Consider adding the namespace

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
```

And add this line inside the class block, at the top

```
use HasApiTokens
```

For new laravel applications, this has already been done, but has been imported from sanctum as `Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens` which does not have the `token()` method.

If so, simply replace `use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens` with `use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens` and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

because it isn't in the table
when you dd( user ) you get all of columns in users table
but in jwt you don't have to store token in database you have to create a code with a Signature ...
but if you want to save token in database :
create a table : jwt tokens
columns : user id , token , created_at ....

i think you can get 'token' with

dd(auth()->user()->token())
or
dd(auth()->user()->accessToken)